# Nested Loops AAE

Tags: loops, nested-loops, automationanywhere

I was trying to nest for loop (for specific times) in loop which was iterating thru list. Like below:
[image]

Result is:

X_Binder:1,
X_Stitcher:2,
X_PolyWrapper:3,
X_Binder:4,
X_Binder:5,
X_Binder:1,
X_Stitcher:2,
X_PolyWrapper:3,
X_Binder:4,
X_Binder:5,
X_Binder:1,
X_Stitcher:2,
X_PolyWrapper:3,
X_Binder:4,
X_Binder:5

instead of:

X_Binder 1,
X_Binder 2,
X_Binder 3,
X_Binder 4,
X_Binder 5,

---

X_Stitcher 1,
X_Stitcher 2,
X_Stitcher 3,
X_Stitcher 4,
X_Stitcher 5,

---

X_PolyWrapper 1,
X_PolyWrapper 2,
X_PolyWrapper 3,
X_PolyWrapper 4,
X_PolyWrapper 5

Can someone explain me what happened? Why it seems like AAE start mixing the order of loops that are iterating.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug that is present in AA for a long time and there doesn't seem to be a will to fix it. Unfortunately, you must remember that **any** loop will cycle through **every** list. This of course makes nested loops completely broken, just like you experienced.

My recommendation is to avoid lists if possible and use XML instead. That allows for greater versatility.